# Unable to get Kafka lag from all partitions

Tags: java, apache-kafka

Is there a way to find whole kafka lag for all consumers assigned to same consumer group?

I could only get the lag for the assigned partition. For e.g. Assume only one partition is assigned to a consumer, below code only brings lag for that partition. Not for other partition.

```
Set<TopicPartition> partitionSet = consumer.assignment();
        Map<TopicPartition, Long> endOffsets = consumer.endOffsets(partitionSet);
for(TopicPartition tp : partitionSet) {
            LOG.info("Topic:{}, EndOffset:{}, currentOffset:{}, LAG:{}",
                    tp.topic(), endOffsets.get(tp), consumer.position(tp), endOffsets.get(tp)-consumer.position(tp));
        }
```

Basically, would like to find the sum of lags from all partitions to understand how much all consumers(same group) of a topic is lagging behind.

Also, is there any api available similar to kafka-consumer-groups, and pass bootstrap-server and group as arguments to find the lag?

./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server  --group  --describe

Comment: kafka-consumer-groups is just a wrapper around a Scala class. You can call it from code

Comment: Alternatively, you can setup external monitoring like Burrow or Prometheus to track all group lags

Answer (score 3):

The correct way to achieve this programmatically is to use the AdminClient API:

1. Get committed offsets for the group using [`listConsumerGroupOffsets()`](http://kafka.apache.org/24/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/Admin.html#listConsumerGroupOffsets-java.lang.String-).
2. Get log end offsets. At the moment you need to start a Consumer and call [`endOffsets()`](http://kafka.apache.org/24/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#endOffsets-java.util.Collection-) for all partitions retrieved in step 1.

   In Kafka 2.5 (expected end of February 2020), there's a new AdminClient API to retrieve log end offsets `listOffsets()` that will enable to solely use the AdminClient to retrieve lag.
3. For each partition, substract the committed offset (step 1) from the log end offset (step 2).

This is basically what `kafka-consumer-groups.sh` does under the covers. So check the [implementation of this tool](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/core/src/main/scala/kafka/admin/ConsumerGroupCommand.scala) if you want.

Comment: yes! [listOffsets()](https://kafka.apache.org/27/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/Admin.html#listOffsets-java.util.Map-) is what i was looking for. Now able to get consumers ofsett without a need of Consumer at all.